# Is there something called "Politely ignores"

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

Can you ignore someone politely. Is it grammatically correct?

> Man offers him a huge reward but he politely ignores him

Comment: Do you mean 'bribe' rather than 'reward'?

Comment: The phrase is altogether unremarkable; there is nothing about it that needs an explanation.

Comment: @jsw29 did you just. .. politely ignore the question? Which is *inherently rude*?

Comment: I ignore 80-90% of the questions here.  It's the polite thing to do.

Comment: @vectory - If it’s not a word request then it’s a philosophical question on whether one can be polite to a person (which requires them to be acknowledged) while at the same time ignoring them.

Comment: @Jim *each and any* question can be philosiphical to a degree. Doesn't mean that the philosophy wouldn't profit from a linguistic tangent.

Comment: it isn't a philosophical question. I got my answer.  Also I have updated the question

Comment: Adding *grammatically* did not improve the question, because now the answer to it is obvious. There is no reason whatsoever to suspect that there is anything **grammatically** wrong about the sentence.

Comment: @jsw29 can u pls correct the question. The answer I was looking for Politely decline or politely refuse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean to communicate that the person did or said something other than simply pretending not to hear the offer, then try *[Decline](https://www.lexico.com/definition/decline)*

> 2. Politely refuse (an invitation or offer)

Even though politeness is embedded in the meaning, there is no harm in saying *politely declined*.

Comment: This is not a word-request question. If it were, this would be a good answer. It's not a bad answer, relative to the lack of information in the question, which might or might not be an actual word request.

Answer (score 0):

There is a spectrum of relevant words. *His offer was disdained* is coloured with discourtesy or even insult. *He made the offer but was snubbed*; to snub is discourteous. *His offer was ignored* is a plain statement but has overtones of discourtesy unless there was a stated good reason (perhaps the room was noisy). *He made the offer but was disregarded* is more neutral than the other two. *Disregard* is often accompanied by an adjective (blatant, callous, wanton) so as to make clear its discourteous nature or by adjectives that make clear the opposite (polite, casual, sober), suggesting that the word itself is rather neutral and not explicitly discourteous; it may be courteous - although not necessarily so.

Despite this line of thought, I cannot conclude my spectrum with a word that suggests indubitably polite disregard. *Disregard* is the best I can offer.

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disregard)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Google Ngram viewer for "politely ignore"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=politely%20ignores&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpolitely%20ignores%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpolitely%20ignores%3B%2Cc0).

You will see that there is nothing remarkable about the phrase: it is part of modern English.

Below the graph, you will also find examples taken from Google Books.

Answer (score -1):

If the quote was an actual quote, word suggestions would be misdirected at our author. That's what I'll assume.

The question is if *ignoring* and being *polite* were inherently at odds. I'm personally interested in that matter.  I figure the semantics of politeness is debatable.

For reference, I translate thusly German *höflich* ("polite") which with *Hof* "court" can mean a rather blunt manerism as a matter of perspective, even if *courtly courtesy* might imply white knights today. This is in line with *polity, polis*, i.e. castles and fortifications, where efficiency is paramount (whereas the party-line politely suggests derivation from *politus* "polished"). More generally, we might also say *civil*.

We can contrast *impolite* and figure that it is the polar opposites. But do we have to? The logic of negation is not straight forward, if the absence of a predicate only weakly implies the possibility of its opposite in existential logic. So if *polite* might mean as much as *not impolite*, it doesn't mean much. Although, the opposite might also hold, so that *not polite* doesn't strictly mean *impolite*. This is ambiguous: it is maybe not ideal, but the ambiguity might be preferable; a local optimum. In logic this would be a pre-order, which is only paraconsistent, not consistent as classical propositional logic would be. *No sooner than 8 o'clock* for example could mean 8 on the second, as a figure of speech, or later, as a matter of fact.

Such logic is especially juicy when it comes to negation in higher orders. *To ignore* is clearly a negative polarity item. However, any negativity could satisfy the predicate. I mean, it could be polite to ignore something.

Further, if we *show ignorance* or *feign desinterest* or the like, it's clear that *to ignore* does not negate all utterance. Thus it is also possible in principle to exhibit some form of politeness while ignoring a particular aspect of the given context.

While the phrase is therefore ambiguous, lexicography could show a prefered idiomatic interpretation, which is however left as exercise to the reader, because it would require a little bit more info about the context--if it might as well be a blooper in place of *to decline* (as @yorik suggested).